# Adding xml prefix declaration with lxml in python

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, lxml, xinclude

**Short version** : 
How to add the xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" prefix decleration to my root element in python with lxml ?

**Context** :

I have some XML files that include IDs to other files.

These IDs represent the referenced file names.

Using lxml I managed to replace these with the appropriate XInclude statement, but if I do not have the prefix decleration my my XML parser won't add the includes, which is normal.

Edit : 
I won't include my code because it won't help at understanding the problem. I can process the document just fine, my problem is serialization.

So from this 
    `<root>
        <somechild/>
    </root>`

I want to get this     `<root xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
        <somechild/>
    </root>` in my output file.

For this I tried using

`

```
tree = ET.parse(fileName)
root = tree.getroot() 
root.nsmap['xi'] = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
tree.write('output.xml', xml_declaration=True, encoding="UTF-8", pretty_print=True)
```

`

Comment: Could you share some code to see how you are using lxml? lxml docs have a few examples on how to use namespaces: [here](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces), [here](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parser-options) and [here](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Attribute `nsmap` is not writable** gives me as error when I try your code.

You can try to register your namespace, remove current attributes (after saving them) of your root element, use `set()` method to add the namespace and recover the attributes.

An example:

```
>>> root = etree.XML('<root a1="one" a2="two"> <somechild/> </root>')
>>> etree.register_namespace('xi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude')
>>> etree.tostring(root)
b'<root a1="one" a2="two"> <somechild/> </root>'
>>> orig_attrib = dict(root.attrib)
>>> root.set('{http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude}xi', '')
>>> for a in root.attrib: del root.attrib[a]
>>> for a in orig_attrib: root.attrib[a] = orig_attrib[a]
>>> etree.tostring(root)
b'<root xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" a1="one" a2="two"> <somechild/> </root>'
>>> root.nsmap
{'xi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I can't test it right now but I'm going to get back to you shortly. In the meantime I made an XSLT transformation that adds the namespace to any XMLs root. I call this transfromation on my root and then it's ok, but your solution seems simpler.